# numpy, fill sparse matrix with rows from other matrix

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice, sparse-matrix

I have trouble figuring out what would be the most efficient way to do the following:

```
import numpy as np

M = 10
K = 10
ind = np.array([0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0])
full = np.random.rand(sum(ind),K)
output = np.zeros((M,K))
output[1,:] = full[0,:]
output[3,:] = full[1,:]
output[7,:] = full[2,:]
```

I want to build output, which is a sparse matrix, whose rows are given in a dense matrix (full) and the row indices are specified through a binary vector.
Ideally, I want to avoid a for-loop. Is that possible? If not, I'm looking for the most efficient way to for-loop this.

I need to perform this operation quite a few times. ind and full will keep changing, hence I've just provided some exemplar values for illustration. 
I expect ind to be pretty sparse (at most 10% ones), and both M and K to be large numbers (10e2 - 10e3). Ultimately, I might need to perform this operation in pytorch, but some decent procedure for numpy, would already get me quite far.

Please also help me find a more appropriate title for the question, if you have one or more appropriate categories for this question.

Many thanks, 
Max

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
output[ind.astype(bool)] = full
```

By converting the integer values in `ind` to boolean values, you can do [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) to select the rows in `output` that you want to populate with values in `full`.

**example with a 4x4 array**:

```
M = 4
K = 4
ind = np.array([0,1,0,1])
full = np.random.rand(sum(ind),K)
output = np.zeros((M,K))

output[ind.astype(bool)] = full

print(output)

[[ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.32434109  0.11970721  0.57156261  0.35839647]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.66038644  0.00725318  0.68902177  0.77145089]]
```